# Global Variables in threads/process [Python]

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this.  I have a script that runs "function_A" and sets some global variables to be used in function "work".  If "function_A" fails, it will run "function_B" which will overwrite the global variables from "function_A" and run function "work" again.

Below is the basic idea:

```
def function_A():
    global data
    global data1
    data = 5 
    data1 = 15
    if host == 1:
        work()
    else:
        function_B()

def function_B():
    global data
    global data1
    data = 3
    data1 = 13
    work()

def work():
    print data
    print data1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = 1
    function_A()
```

Sample output if function_A does not fail:

```
test$ python test.py
5
15
```

Sample output if function_A does fail:

```
test$ python test.py
3
13
```

The real script is much more complex than this, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't a better way of doing this, I will be using multiprocessing module with this.

EDIT:

Thanks, here is the same script with parameters passing:

```
def function_A():
    data = 5
    data1 = 15
    if host == 1:
        work(data, data1)
    else:
        function_B()

def function_B():
    data = 3
    data1 = 13
    work(data, data1)

def work(data,data1):
    print data
    print data1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = 11
    function_A()
```

Comment: Yes, there is: pass them as parameters. You can group them into dictionaries if there are lots of them. It is very easy to lose track of variables if modified globally. It has nothing to do with neither threads nor processes.

Comment: Thanks, very much.  That seems much better now!!